# Avoid data loss on update while using Memory-Optimized Tables

Tags: sql-server, transactions, memory-optimized-tables

My company main software have 90% of the business logic on the database (stored procedures). With the last version, Memory-Optimized Tables have been introduced to replace temporary tables used to pass data between procedures. The software used to rely on SNAPSHOT isolation to avoid losing data due to concurrent transaction updating the same records, but now the isolation level has been changed to READ COMMITED SNAPSHOT (in order to use MO Tables).

Since a LOT of the software logic looks like this:

```
DECLARE @IdLocationsToUpdate TABLE (Id BIGINT)


INSERT INTO @IdLocationsToUpdate (Id)
SELECT Id FROM Warehouse.LocationEntity WHERE ..... -- Complex conditions or other inner joins


UPDATE l
Warehouse.LocationEntity l
INNER JOIN @IdLocationsToUpdate lu ON lu.Id = l.Id

-- Plus multiple other updates and logics on that list of Ids
```

We are now having issue with UPDATES due to the missing SNAPSHOT. That's because the records selected and inserted into the table variable, may have been updated by another transaction and the update statement should not be executed now since the conditions are not met anymore by some of those records. Before, this was avoided by the exceptions thrown by the SNAPSHOT isolation that didn't allow the multiple update on the same record.

What do you suggest to do?

Hope the explanation was clear enough. Thanks in advance.

A first idea would be to rewrite the WHERE condition used in the first select, in all the subsequent updates, but that would make the code way longer and confused. So i was hoping for a solution to remove the data loss while avoiding duplicated code, or a way of re-enabling snapshot isolation.

Comment: Don't want to bash memory tables but i haven't noticed any huge performance wins in those. Have you actually measured the performance improvements that make this a valid path to use?

Comment: I didn't personally test the performance before and after an i'm not aware of any clear performance improvement, so i can't really say if this was the best way go to.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing to do for starters is to begin and commit a transaction.

But you also need to add the `UPDLOCK` hint otherwise it doesn't know you still want those rows to be modified.

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;  -- always use this for better error handling and rollback

BEGIN TRAN;

DECLARE @IdLocationsToUpdate TABLE (Id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY);  -- ideally add a primary key

INSERT INTO @IdLocationsToUpdate (Id)
SELECT Id
FROM Warehouse.LocationEntity WITH (UPDLOCK)
WHERE ..... -- Complex conditions or other inner joins


UPDATE l
Warehouse.LocationEntity l
INNER JOIN @IdLocationsToUpdate lu ON lu.Id = l.Id

COMMIT;
```

Quite why you are using temp tables in the first place is not clear: the above simplified code (even with "complex" joins) certainly doesn't need it. Most code which uses temp tables doesn't actually need it, and needlessly complicates things and causes performance issues.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, so the UPDLOCK will make the insert wait for any other transaction that didn't commit yet, correct? In this way we move more towards pessimistic handling instead of going full optimistic, but it's definitely a valid option.

The sample code i provided was just to give an idea, instead of a simple update that list of Ids is actually stored in a UDT and passed as parameter to other procedure that handle those data. Also the temporary tables were used to pass and return list of data between the high number of stored procedure we have.

Comment: `UPDLOCK` does two things: it takes out a U lock and it extends the length of the lock. U locks need to wait for U and X locks, but not for S locks. Actual modification queries do so under U and then X locks, but simple reads only under S locks. It also extends the lock to the end of the transaction. These two together mean that pessimistic locking should be utilized, the same way as any modification query (where U lock is taken out first then upgraded to X).